# Slim Rails Tables Using .each Over an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

My table works fine when I put `= list.title` above the `tr` element, but when I move it below into a `td` cell, I get an `undefined method` list error. I am new to slim and templating engines. Can you suggest how to format this correctly? Also is there a thorough syntax guide our there on slim? I tried to Google around, but could not find exactly what I had hoped for.

```
table
        thead
          tr
              th
                  | Title
              th
                  | Description
              th
                  | Image URL
              th
                  | Price
        tbody
            - @products.each do |list|
            tr
              td
                = list.title
              td
                = list.description
              td
                = list.image_url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there is indentation problem. You should have the `tr` tag and its children one `indent` inside. i.e. the `- @products.each do |list|` should enclose the items.

```
        - @products.each do |list|
          tr
            td
              = list.title
            td
              = list.description
            td
              = list.image_url
```